# Parent widget accessing GlobalKey simultaneously?

Tags: flutter, dart

This could be a simple oversight, but consider the following code block:

```
final webViewKey = GlobalKey<WebViewContainerState>();
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
...
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: getOptions(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Flexible(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: WebViewContainer(
                key: webViewKey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
      } else {
        return const Text('');
      }
    },
  ),
```

This results in the error:

```
The key [LabeledGlobalKey<WebViewContainerState>#0d5fc] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were:
- WebViewContainer-[LabeledGlobalKey<WebViewContainerState>#0d5fc](state: WebViewContainerState#d188a)
- SizedBox(renderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#de300 relayoutBoundary=up2)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
```

The key `webViewKey` is specified inside `WebViewContainer()`, which is a child of the `SizedBox()` widget.

Why is `SizedBox()` accessing this key in the first place, and how do you prevent this error from happening within this context?

Comment: try to rename the key as local variable by adding `_` to the variable name.  so your key name will be `_webViewKey`

Comment: @pmatatias ah good suggestion, but unfortunately did not change the complaint of `SizedBox()` accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

try to Make it a Unique key to solve the error.

Comment: You need to clarify a little more. Global keys must be unique across an app by default. `UniqueKey` is a type of `LocalKey` from what I can tell, which does not solve the issue of using a `GlobalKey`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your `global key` to something else.

Because it can happen that the name of your `global key` and the name of the key that is used in the `webView` can be the same.